# Local database with Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**Visual Basic 2010 Express**, lets the user to add a *Local Database* with .sdf extension. These databases needs *MICROSOFT SQL Server* to be created or they can run in the user's pc without any additional software? What are the limit of these databases unlike an external database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Sql Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).  Compact Edition is an in-process/desktop/embedded/file-based database — like Access or sqlite.  It's free, and much easier to deploy than a full Sql Server edition.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You will need a installation of Microsoft SQL Server® 2008 Express, which is free to download.
Download can be found at [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en-us/details.aspx?FamilyID=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff).</strike>

Comparison between Express and compact version can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compare-specialized.aspx), this also shows the given limits of the express version:

- Max 1 CPU/Server
- 1 GB RAM usage
- 4 GB DB size

**EDIT**:
You can find a wider comparison from Enterprise to Express editions [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx).

**EDIT 2:**
My mistake. Of course SDF is indeed for **Compact** version, not for Express.
The compact version is free to download and available at Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876).